# What gives the US federal government the power to set a minimum wage?

Tags: united-states, constitutional-law

How can the federal government set a minimum wage? It seems like that would be reserved to the states under the 10th Amendment.

Is the interstate commerce clause? That seems iffy to me.

Comment: Iffier than the impact of wheat grown on your own farm for personal use has on interstate wheat prices? Wickard v Fillburn settled that.

Answer (score 3):

It's the interstate commerce clause. Because of how the modern economy works. there's really pretty much nothing that's confined to a single state in its effects and doesn't affect other states. Almost any law can be justified as a regulation of interstate commerce these days, especially if that law is actually directly about commercial activity.

The big case to cite here is *United States v. Darby* ([312 US 100](https://scholar.google.com/scholar_case?case=1183543472021488573)). This case tested a federal minimum wage law which banned shipping goods in interstate commerce where they were produced by people paid less than minimum wage, and also banned the employment of those people at less than minimum wage in that context. The Supreme Court found this law constitutional, even though the manufacturing employees weren't personally engaged in interstate commerce, because the employer *was* engaged in interstate commerce and regulating production was a permissible way to regulate that commerce.

Now, after that decision, there was a major broadening of what was allowed to be regulated under the interstate commerce clause. In *Wickard v. Filburn* ([317 US 111](https://scholar.google.com/scholar_case?case=17396018701671434685)), the Supreme Court ruled that the appropriate test to see whether something could be regulated as interstate commerce was whether it had a "substantial economic effect" on interstate commerce. Under this rule, federal regulation under the commerce clause is very far-reaching. It supports extending a minimum wage to domestic service workers ([*Marshall v. Rose*](https://scholar.google.com/scholar_case?case=6853240429044189885), a Fourth Circuit case from 1980); it supports extending EEOC rules to state employers ([*EEOC v. Wyoming*](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/460/226/case.html)); it supports a *lot* of things.

Comment: I'd be curious to know whether this has been considered by the Supreme Court.  All I could find was *West Coast Hotel v. Parrish* (1937), which overturned earlier decisions and held that a *state* minimum wage law was constitutional.  But of course this doesn't have the Tenth Amendment issue, and *West Coast Hotel* predates the introduction of a *federal* minimum wage with the Fair Labor Standards Act of 1938.

Comment: *US v. Darby* ([312 US 100](https://scholar.google.com/scholar_case?case=1183543472021488573&q=minimum+wage+%22domestic+service%22+commerce&hl=en&as_sdt=4,60)). Even for things so seemingly separate from interstate commerce as domestic service employees, the 4th Circuit found it clearly within the scope of the clause in [*Marshall v. Rose*](https://scholar.google.com/scholar_case?case=6853240429044189885&hl=en&as_sdt=5,60&sciodt=3,60).

Comment: What I'd like to know is how both a state minimum wage AND a federal minimum wage can both be constitutional at the same time.  If the 10th amendment reserves all powers not in the constitution to the states, and the minimum wage is a constitutional power, then how is it that states have the power left over to enact their own minimum wage laws?

Comment: @Mr.A States can generally regulate commerce; they can't regulate in a discriminatory way against interstate commerce (for instance, they can't say "landfills can't import garbage from other states"), but there's nothing unconstitutional about a state regulating something that happens to also be interstate commerce. I'm not sure how you're reading the Tenth Amendment to say "there is nothing that is under the power of both the feds and the states;" that only works if everything the feds can control is something the states cannot touch, which is not true.

Comment: @Mr.A Unless you think the Tenth Amendment is a grant of powers? Because it's not. States have a general police power to regulate *anything* absent a specific reason they're *not* allowed to regulate it. If the Constitution delegates something to the feds, it doesn't automatically take it wholly outside the realm of state regulation. Federal laws override conflicting state ones, but if the Constitution doesn't ban the states from doing something and the feds don't decide to preempt state laws, states can still regulate.

Comment: For example...Congress shall have the power to declare war...then by the 10th amendment the states do not have the power to declare war...no?

Comment: @Mr.A No. That's why Article I, Section 10 exists: it says that states can't do *some* things that Congress has the power to do. For instance, states can't states can't engage in war (unless invaded or in imminent danger) without congressional approval because Article I says so. States can't run their own immigration because the federal scheme is so complete that it leaves no room for any state regulation, so the Supremacy Clause stops the states from interfering. The 10th Amendment says states keep anything not delegated to the feds; it doesn't say they lose what *was* delegated.

Comment: @Mr.A It's worth noting that federal and state minimum wage laws don't conflict: an employer can comply with both by simply paying the higher of the two wages.  Under the Commerce clause, Congress probably *could* make a law that said "The minimum wage is $X.XX, and no state shall set one that is higher."  But they have not done so.